# Merge multiple csv files to xls file in separate tabs using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to read multiple csv files using Python and those csv files needs to be added to a single xls file in separate tabs. I have the code for that and it is working fine for me. But the csv files were having both the string and the numbers in different columns, when it get merge all the strings and the numbers were converted as a string and it shows the error message in the excel. I want the numbers to be in the same format when it get merged.

**Code**:

!/usr/bin/env python

```
import os
import glob
import csv
import xlwt
from openpyxl import Workbook
fpath = "C:/Project/Phase 3/Corrected code/"
wb = xlwt.Workbook() 
os.chdir(fpath)
flist = os.listdir(fpath)
print flist
for csvfile in flist:
fname = csvfile.split(".")
print (" The File Name is "+fname[0])
ws = wb.add_sheet(fname[0])
with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for r, row in enumerate(reader):
        for c, col in enumerate(row):
            ws.write(r, c, col)`enter code here`

wb.save('Percentage_query.xls')
```

Please help me out for this conversion.

Comment: please correct grammar error such as `i` instead of `I`

Comment: *"numbers were converted as a string"*: Reading from `CSV` is allways of type `str`. If you want `int` do `int(col)`.